# Absolute positioned h1 title moves downwards on scroll down

Tags: html, css

I have an h1 title:

```
 <h1 class="main-heading"><span class="heading-opaque-background"><%= @post.title %></span></h1>
```

Absolutely positioned over a header picture:

```
.main-heading {
    /*TEXT ON MAIN PIC*/
      position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    /*height: 40px;*/
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 4vw;
      height: 20%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #999999, 0 2px 0 #888888,
    0 3px 0 #777777, 0 4px 0 #666666,
    0 5px 0 #555555, 0 6px 0 #444444,
    0 7px 0 #333333, 0 8px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
    0 9px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}
```

When I scroll down, the header moves down towards the bottom of the pic. Setting display to inline doesn't change anything.

How can I make the title stay absolutely positioned over the picture?

Here is a more complete overview of the html, to show parent classes:

```
<img class="project-main-pic" src="<%= Citybuilder.ProjectPic.url({@post.project_pic, @post}) %>" />
<!--f https://image.slidesharecdn.com/otpphoenixecto-170327125511/95/yurii-bodarev-otp-phoenix-ecto-three-pillars-of-elixir-58-638.jpg?cb=1490619720-->
<section id="home" class="">
    <h1 class="main-heading"><span class="heading-opaque-background"><%= @post.title %></span></h1>
</section>
<div class="project-wrapper">
    <section id="about" class="sec-about">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="project-title"><%= @post.title %></h1>
            <!-- ADD TO FORM AND DATABASE -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <p class="summary-text">
                        <%= @post.body %>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Provide a JSfiddle or something, also why using height:20%?

Comment: Please provide styles applicable to the element in question (`h1`) as well.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, I have no specific layout styles for h1. main-heading is the only class acting on this element. Unless I missed something.

Comment: I suggest you have to use position fixed with a top of 0 px

Comment: @YingYang. I need the title to stay where it is. Position: fixed will make it move when i scroll. Right now, it moves on scrolldown.

Comment: @RubyRube no, it looks like I was - my mistake. I get the impression that another element is a result of this adverse affect. Are there new styles being applied to the body, or any parent element of `.main-heading`, when you scroll? Something could be adding in `padding` or `margin` values. And if the `absolute` positioned element is nested within a `relative` positioned parent element these rules could affect positioning.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, I copypasted the wrong code block when I first wrote the question. Apologies. The correct block (including position: absolute), is now in the OP. I added more html to the OP. Yes, I will check the parent classes and elements, because it looks like other styles are acting on the h1.

Comment: @RubyRube if you can give me a direct link, I'm sure I can help you. But as it stands now, I don't have a big enough picture to frame the issue and provide a solution.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError same problem here :) RubyRube I think you have to use position relative(relative to the pic) then and use a negative top (height of the title)

Comment: UncaughtTypeError I will try and move it onto a Codepen, but I have a feeling it would work OK in isolation, and the problem is hidden CSS classes in my framework, maybe from Bootstrap. YingYang, I'll try that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check it here: https://jsbin.com/cezidexase/1/edit?html,css,output

```
.main-heading {
    margin: auto;
    /*height: 40px;*/
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.80);
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 4vw;
      height: 20%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #999999, 0 2px 0 #888888,
    0 3px 0 #777777, 0 4px 0 #666666,
    0 5px 0 #555555, 0 6px 0 #444444,
    0 7px 0 #333333, 0 8px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
    0 9px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}
```

Comment: That's working fine in isolation, but I don't know how it works with the hidden classes in my CSS, which Im trying to trace.

Comment: Sharing Plunker would help

Comment: @RubyRube If you inspect element and keep the IDE open, with the element in question selected (so that all applicable styles are visible), then scroll, you should be able to pick up on any additional styles being applied or unset.

Comment: @ UncaughtTypeError I will do that next, thanks. I made a codepen with the html and css. https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/oeOWWe Its working fine. So it must be some hidden parent classes, as you guessed.

Answer (score -1):

for this use

`.main-heading{position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;}`

or use special plugin for this, he re is a 
[sample](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/)

Comment: . I need the title to stay where it is. Position: fixed will make it move when I scroll. Right now, it moves on scrolldown Position absolute doesn't seem to position it enough.

Comment: @RubyRube i need to see full code, try to use sticky-kit plugin for fix block on scrol

Comment: Hi Dmitry. Thanks, but I need an absolutely positioned title, not position fixed.